# "Check For Updates" disabled (grayed out) using Sparkle framework

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5, sparkle

I'm using Sparkle to distribute updates to my OS X app. It's working well for most of my users but I'm getting reports from a small number saying that "Check For Updates" is disabled.

The only other examples I can find online are from developers who NEVER see "Check For Updates" enabled. In my case, the whole process is working great for most customers; only a few are experiencing this.

I'm not doing anything tricky. I'm set up exactly like the documentation describes (https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/wiki), including signing the framework with my developer ID. And again, it works for most.

Right now the users who are having trouble are running OS X 10.9.4 but I can't confirm if there are 10.9.4 users for whom it works.

Comment: Ask the affected customers to check their system console logs for any other clues about what could be going wrong. As a rule, the menu item will be greyed out if the target of the item is nil. What object specifically does the menu item target, and how could it come to be nil at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's expected behavior.

When you checked the "Automatically download and install updates in the future", Sparkle will download the dmg in background and **disable the menu**. App will be updated on next launch.

Comment: Just noticed I hadn't accepted this answer. I suspect that was the "problem".

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I didn't realize this was expected behavior. What I encountered as a macOS app developer was, when launching the app from Xcode the "Check for Updates..." button would be enabled but would get disabled whenever I ran the app manually on the same system. I had clicked 'Automatic download' as you mentioned causing the menu to be disabled. Works fine on new machines :) Cheers!

Comment: Good to know it's expected behavior. Is there any way we could enable the "Check for Updates..." button though -- even on systems where the user has selected "Automatic download"? It would be great for more urgent/critical updates so that users don't have to wait for Sparkle to check. Thanks!